# What is the significance of the Tanaan-wide yell by the Bleeding Hollow Herald?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Sometimes when I am adventuring in Tanaan Jungle (in World of Warcraft: Warlords of Draenor expansion patch 6.2) I see a zone-wide yell:

> Bleeding Hollow Herald yells: The Blood Moon rises and strengthens our
>   chieftain!  Rejoice Bleeding Hollow, soon he will be unstoppable!

What is the significance of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Bleeding Hollow Herald's yell indicates that the Blood Moon event is active. It causes a large, well, blood moon to appear Zeth'gol. In order to damage the blood moon, you'll need to find these small crystals that spawn, and loot them. After looting the crystal, you'll get an item in your inventory which will allow you to preform a short channel, damaging the blood moon. When the blood moon reaches 0%, it will spawn a Remnant of the Blood Moon, which has a chance to drop the Vial of Red Goo toy (drop rate seems to be ~35% on Wowhead). The Remnant also functions like a normal rare.

This is one of several yells to announce an event is starting. Others include the spawn of several super rares: Vengeance, Deathtalon, Doomrollers, and Terrorfist.

> - Frogan yells: A massive gronnling is heading for Rangari Refuge! We are going to require some assistance! (Terrorfist)
> - Shadow Lord Iskar yells: Behind the veil, all you find is death! (Deathtalon)
> - Tyrant Velhari yells: Insects deserve to be crushed! (Vengeance)
> - Siegemaster Mar'tak yells: Hah-ha! Trample their corpses! (Doomroller)

Each of the rares or super rares can be looted once per day per character.

Comment: The Herald indicates that the Blood Moon event is active. It's a pretty simple event where you gather these small usable items and then use them to slightly damage the Blood Moon. It can take a while, but has a chance to reward a toy.